# Prove: $\{f: \int |f|^2 \leq 1\}$ is closed in $L^1$ and has empty interior and the inclusion map $L^2$ into $L^1$ is continuous but not onto.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

By looking at suggested answers, I now know that this follows from the fact that L2 is meager in L1. Is there anything I need to add or change to the following?

(1.) Let $L^1$ and $L^2$ be the usual Lebesgue spaces over the interval $[0,1]$. Prove the following statements:
(a.) $\{f: \int |f|^2 \leq 1\}$ is closed in $L^1$ and has empty interior.
(b.) The inclusion map $L^2$ into $L^1$ is continuous but not onto.

(a.)  Let $A=\{f: \int_0^1 |f|^2 \leq 1\}$. Let $(f_n)\in A$ let $f_n\to f$ then $f\in A$ we want to show that $f\in L^1$. Consider $\int|f|\leq (\int |f|^2 \int 1)^{1/2}=(\int |f|^2)^{1/2}\leq 1$ Since $\int |f|\leq 1$ we have $f\in L^1$.  Take $g\in L^1/ L^2$ and consider $h_n=f + \frac{g}{n}$ then $h_n\to h$ and $h_n\in L^1/L^2$ and $h \in L^1$.  And this shows the set has empty interior? 
(b.) Let $I:L^2 \to L^1$ be the inclusion map. So for $f\in L^2$ $I(f)=f$, clearly I is continuous because it is well known that the identity map is continuous and I is not surjective because $f=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is in $L^1$ but not $L^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed in $L^{1}$ means closed w.r.t. the norm of $L^{1}$. There are two norms involved here.  So you should avoid saying $f_n \to f$ without specifying the metric.

Let $f_n \in A$ for all $n$ and $\|f_n-f\|_1 \to 0$. Then there is a subsequence  $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ converging to $f$ a.e..  By Fatou's Lemma we get $\int |f|^{2} \leq \lim \inf \int |f_{n_k}|^{2} \leq 1$. This proves that $A$ is closed w.r.t. $L^{1}$ norm.

For showing that $A$ has empty interior in $L^{1}$ your construction works. (You forgot to start with the statement 'let $f \in A$'.

Your answer for the last part is correct.